# Options on sale of a Ltd Company

Tags: employee-stock-options

I have options in a Limited Fin Tech start up company. The options are based upon the company achieving profitability.

It now appears likely that the company is to be acquired at a substantial price but is actually still loss making.

The options make no mention of what happens on an acquisition .

What is the legal situation ?

Comment: Have the options vested? Can you afford to buy the shares at the strike price.

Comment: legal situation requires a country

Comment: I have (technically) already bought the options... the country is the UK

Answer (score 1):

From you what you have written, the options have not vested. There is also no strike price mentioned in the options.

So this looks like a vaguely worded document, there maybe little to force the current company into doing something meaningful.

Generally under such situation, the acquiring company will make a good will gesture and pay a token amount and get rid of the options. So it all depends, there is very little that can be enforced.